# Conditional outcome

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong? Im trying to get a green text if conditions are met, or normal text when not.

This is my code:

```
if($result)
{
    echo ("<br> <u><b><h2>Totaal:</h2></b></u> <br>") ;

        if($formatted_one <= $formatted_two || $formatted_one <= $formatted_three || $formatted_one <= $formatted_four )
        {
        echo ("<b><font color='green'> Opties Brons</font></b><br> ") ;
        echo "Pakket Brons: &#8364 " . ($formatted_one) . "<br>" ;
        echo "Pakket Brons: &#8364 " . ($formatted_one_one) . " (inclusief all-in pakket) <br>" ;
        echo "<b>Het verschil is: &#8364 " . ($formatted_one_two) . " </b><br>" ;
        echo ("<br>") ;
        }
        else
        {
        echo ("<b>Opties Brons</b><br> ") ;
        echo "Pakket Brons: &#8364 " . ($formatted_one) . "<br>" ;
        echo "Pakket Brons: &#8364 " . ($formatted_one_one) . " (inclusief all-in pakket) <br>" ;
        echo "<b>Het verschil is: &#8364 " . ($formatted_one_two) . " </b><br>" ;
        echo ("<br>") ;
} 
else
{
    echo("<br>U heeft niet alles goed ingevuld");
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you may find this reference useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself (please note, this isn't meant to be humorous, I needed a lot of time and practice to properly use DRY principles)

Comment: (anyway, the problem of this code is that you're lacking the inner else closed curly brace at the end...)

Comment: The conditional has `$formatted_two` and `$formatted_three` but `$formatted_one_one` and `$formatted_one_two` elsewhere. Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, please don't use `<font>`. It's not 1995 anymore.

Comment: I believe there are cleaner and more sophisticated ways. However I'm on day three now of my brilliant plan to do it myself, so 'it works' is good enough for now :)

Comment: @Juhana Yes, they are three different values.

Comment: @user3069332 please remember this: there is **NO BETTER TIME** to learn proper good feature than when you've **just begun** your journey. Spend some more hours **NOW** and save yourself several **DAYS** of struggle later

Answer (score 0):

your

```
} else {
    echo ("<b>Opties Brons</b><br> ") ;
```

never close...

so you actualy have

```
if() {
   ...
} else {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

this wrong, add the missing `}`

Comment: I don't see how it doesn't close. Also when I add a } , I get a error message?

Comment: Ahh, I found it... My appologies! Thanks for the help